# How to compare and see if an expanded command is equal to another

Tags: macros, expansion, datatool, compare

Okay, I'm processing a CSV file using datatool:

```
"TRANSID","DATE","QUANTITY"
"141f8b4a-e83e-4222-911a-5a977b4d0afca","11/9/2015","10"
"88cdad7e-eb21-4010-94c5-acca8ac2e559a","11/9/2015","5"
"f15c1ef0-316b-4fdd-9c3a-8a111d60d27da","11/9/2015","50"
"f15c1ef0-316b-4fdd-9c3a-8a111d60d27da","11/9/2015","50"
```

The problem is I'd like for the last two lines to be combined onto a single page, so I need to check and see if they're equivalent --- not having any luck w/ that:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{C:/Users/wfadams/Desktop/heiferinvoice/test.csv}

\newcommand{\oldtransactionid}{false}

\newboolean{continuerecord}
\setboolean{continuerecord}{false}

\begin{document}%
Initial setup here\par
%
\DTLforeach*{data}{%
\orderNo=TRANSID, \date=DATE, \quantity=QUANTITY}%
{%
\DTLiffirstrow{Processing first record}{second or further record}%
%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{continuerecord}}%
{Continuing a record\par}%
{Not continuing a record, clear to new page\par}%false
%
\hspace*{-3bp}\fontsize{10bp}{22bp}\selectfont\hbox to 42bp{\quantity}\hbox to 72bp{\hspace*{30bp} \quantity}\hbox to 144bp{\hspace*{15bp}ITEMCODE}\hbox to 288bp{\hspace*{15bp}\orderNo\hfill}\par
%
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\expandafter\oldtransactionid}{\expandafter\orderNo}%
{\setboolean{continuerecord}{true}T\par}%
{\setboolean{continuerecord}{false}F\par}%
OLD: \oldtransactionid \par
NEW: \orderNo\par
\edef\oldtransactionid{\orderNo}
}%
%
place last page here
\end{document}
```

I thinking adding \edef got me to the last hurdle --- I jut need a way to get the comparison to work properly --- and obviously the \expandafter commands aren't helping (also tried \immediate (which as egreg noted isn't right)).

also tried:

```
\expandafter\ifstrequal{\expandafter{\oldtransactionid}}{\expandafter{\orderNo}}%
```

As well as a crazy idea of writing out to scratch files and reading back in, which I'm sufficiently embarrassed by as to not be willing to show.

Comment: `\immediate` does nothing unless followed by `\write`, `\openout` or `\closeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand both macros passed to `\ifstrequal`, but the string of `\expandafter`s you're using only affects the first (and not really, I'd say).

The standard technique, if the data is ASCII strings, is to use `\edef`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
"TRANSID","DATE","QUANTITY"
"141f8b4a-e83e-4222-911a-5a977b4d0afca","11/9/2015","10"
"88cdad7e-eb21-4010-94c5-acca8ac2e559a","11/9/2015","5"
"f15c1ef0-316b-4fdd-9c3a-8a111d60d27da","11/9/2015","50"
"f15c1ef0-316b-4fdd-9c3a-8a111d60d27da","11/9/2015","50"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{\jobname.csv}

\newcommand{\oldtransactionid}{false}

\newboolean{continuerecord}
\setboolean{continuerecord}{false}

\begin{document}

Initial setup here

\DTLforeach*{data}{\orderNo=TRANSID, \date=DATE, \quantity=QUANTITY}%
  {%
   \DTLiffirstrow{Processing first record}{second or further record}%
   %
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{continuerecord}}%
     {Continuing a record\par}%
     {Not continuing a record, clear to new page\par}%false
   %
   \hspace*{-3bp}\fontsize{10bp}{22bp}\selectfont\hbox to 42bp{\quantity}%
   \hbox to 72bp{\hspace*{30bp} \quantity}%
   \hbox to 144bp{\hspace*{15bp}ITEMCODE}%
   \hbox to 288bp{\hspace*{15bp}\orderNo\hfill}\par
   %
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
     \noexpand\ifstrequal{\oldtransactionid}{\orderNo}%
   }\x
   {\setboolean{continuerecord}{true}T\par}%
   {\setboolean{continuerecord}{false}F\par}%
   OLD: \oldtransactionid \par
   NEW: \orderNo\par
   \edef\oldtransactionid{\orderNo}
  }

place last page here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I seem to've gotten it to work w/: \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter{\oldtransactionid}}{\expandafter{\orderNo}}}%

Comment: @WillAdams I don't think the `\expandafter` are necessary; however, I wouldn't recommend `\ifthenelse`.